# is this a valid interpretation of the composite pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, composite

One recommendation I get out of the composite pattern is to provide default operations that handle inappropriate child management operations for a Leaf node (ie, throwing an exception on AddChild, returning an empty enumeration for Children, etc.).

My understanding of the classic pattern is to have a single abstract class with a Leaf subclass and a Composite subclass but if you provide default ops in the parent, doesn't it effectively obviate the need for the Leaf?

Does anyone do it this way?

Cheers,
Berryl

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's possible we're talking about different things.  i am assuming the composite pattern is as described on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern

for that pattern, you would not expose operations that don't apply to the leaf node, like `AddChild` (your example) because the `Component` interface (using the names from the wikipedia article) is intended to expose only common actions that can be performed on either a leaf or a node.  so there is no need for defaults.

there is an `add()` on the `Composite` class in the wikipedia article, but that is to add things to the composite "view", not to any particular data structure.  in other words, you might access some parts of a tree of data through a composite interface, but the `add()` method on the interface is adding or removing items from that collection, and not from the tree itself.

Comment: nah, its the same pattern but the wikipedia article refers to the way I learned it from GoF as a [Variation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern#Variation), implying its a bit dated too!. I forget just how useful wikipedia is sometimes.

Comment: just to clarify, where to put AddChild has always been a subject of debate. If you make it part of the interface, then clients of the composite need not care if they are in fact dealing with a Leaf or a Composite, which the GoF preferred for that reason (you also don't have to cast the component to a composite on the AddChild). The price being that you have a method that is not natural to that class, which is why the author or the wikiopedia article preferred to have all child management ops in the composite only.

Comment: what I wound up doing in *this* particular case is decide that I really just had a single tree structure without a compelling need for Leaf nodes or the Composite pattern, and just collapsed the GeographicBoundaryComposite into the GeographicBoundary. Cheers